# How to put valid numbers in python

Tags: python

I wanted my program to check if the code was a valid number
A valid number in my case is :123, 43.76, 89, 100000, 78765.987 etc. infinite
NoN_valid_number: 123abc, 7.9.8, afadf, *&^dadsf ... etc

- How do I implent this in python

```py
y = 11SS # it doesnt let me input this value and I get an error

if type(y) == int or float:
    print('valid')
else: 
    print('non valid')
```

Comment: "I get an error"—please read [ask]. "An error" is not helpful. The _specific, exact, complete_ error _would_ be helpful. Please read [ask].

Comment: ...do you expect `11SS` to be valid for some reason? How is that a valid number?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is that you are effectively setting y to a string without putting the quotes around it. Try `y = "11SS"`